# what is the difference between form and chtml in yii

Tags: forms, yii

confusion between form and chtml

i used to form to write form ans submit to database working fine, but for some particular places, according to  google search used CHTML instead of form. but when i submitted that form to database

CHTML textfield value is not submitting to database

here goes my code

**_Form.php**

```
 <script language="javascript">

function firstlang(flang,slang,tlang,math,scien,soci)
{

var sflang=parseInt(flang)+parseInt(slang)+parseInt(tlang)+parseInt(math)+parseInt(scien)+parseInt(soci);
document.getElementById('totalmarks').value=sflang;
if(sflang>=300 && sflang<400)
{
var flang='C';
document.getElementById('grade').value=flang;
}
else if(sflang>=400 && sflang<500)
{
var flang='B';
document.getElementById('grade').value=flang;   
}
else if(sflang>=550 && sflang<=600)
{
var flang='A';
document.getElementById('grade').value=flang;   
}
}

</script>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'marks-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
     'enableClientValidation'=>true,
      'focus'=>array($model,'class'),
)); ?>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'class'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row">

   <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('class','',CHtml::listData(class1::model()->findAll(),'class','class'),array('empty'=>'Choose one',

'ajax' => array(

'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('Marks/dynamicstates'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#studentid', //selector to update
//'data'=>'js:javascript statement'
//leave out the data key to pass all form values through
)));

//empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'class'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'studentid'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo CHtml::dropdownlist('studentid','',array()); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'studentid'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'examtype'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'examtype',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>30)); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'examtype'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firsttlanguage'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'firsttlanguage',array('id'=>'firsttlanguage','value'=>'0','onkeyup'=>'firstlang(this.value,secondlanguage.value,thirdlanguage.value,mathematics.value,science.value,social.value)')); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'firsttlanguage'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'secondlanguage'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'secondlanguage',array('id'=>'secondlanguage','value'=>'0','onkeyup'=>'firstlang(this.value,firsttlanguage.value,thirdlanguage.value,mathematics.value,science.value,social.value)')); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'secondlanguage'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'thirdlanguage'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'thirdlanguage',array('id'=>'thirdlanguage','value'=>'0','onkeyup'=>'firstlang(this.value,firsttlanguage.value,secondlanguage.value,mathematics.value,science.value,social.value)')); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'thirdlanguage'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mathematics'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'mathematics',array('id'=>'mathematics','value'=>'0','onkeyup'=>'firstlang(this.value,firsttlanguage.value,secondlanguage.value,thirdlanguage.value,science.value,social.value)')); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'mathematics'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'science'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'science',array('id'=>'science','value'=>'0','onkeyup'=>'firstlang(this.value,firsttlanguage.value,secondlanguage.value,thirdlanguage.value,mathematics.value,social.value)')); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'science'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'social'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'social',array('id'=>'social','value'=>'0','onkeyup'=>'firstlang(this.value,firsttlanguage.value,secondlanguage.value,thirdlanguage.value,mathematics.value,science.value)')); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'social'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'totalmarks'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'totalmarks',array('id'=>'totalmarks','size'=>5,'maxlength'=>5)); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'totalmarks'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'grade'); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'grade',array('id'=>'grade','size'=>5,'maxlength'=>5)); ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="row"><?php echo $form->error($model,'grade'); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span class="row buttons"><?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>





<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

**MarksController.php**

```
<?php

class MarksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','dynamicstates'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Marks;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Marks']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Marks'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Marks']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Marks'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Marks');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Marks('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Marks']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Marks'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Marks::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='marks-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
public function actiondynamicstates()
{

      // $model1=new Examresults;
        /*$exam_type=(int)$_POST['exam_type'];


        if ($exam_type==0)
                $data=array(0=>'States:');
        else if ($exam_type==1)
                $data=array(1=>'Alaska', 2=>'California');    
        else if ($exam_type==2)
                $data=array(1=>'Orleans', 2=>'Bordeaux');
        else if ($exam_type==3)
                $data=array(1=>'Hokkaido', 2=>'Okinawa');*/
//$schoolfee = feesettings::model()->find("feetype='schoolfee' and class='".$_REQUEST['class']."'");

 $data=admission::model()->findAll('class=:class',
                  array(':class'=>$_POST['class']));


   $data=CHtml::listData($data,'studentid','studentfname');

        foreach($data as $value=>$name)
                echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value), CHtml::encode($name), true);

}

}
```

**Marks.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "marks".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'marks':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $class
 * @property string $studentid
 * @property string $examtype
 * @property integer $firsttlanguage
 * @property integer $secondlanguage
 * @property integer $thirdlanguage
 * @property integer $mathematics
 * @property integer $science
 * @property integer $social
 * @property integer $totalmarks
 * @property string $grade
 */
class Marks extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Marks the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'marks';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('class, studentid', 'required'),
            array('firsttlanguage, secondlanguage, thirdlanguage, mathematics, science, social, totalmarks', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('class, studentid, examtype', 'length', 'max'=>30),
            array('grade', 'length', 'max'=>5),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, class, studentid, examtype, firsttlanguage, secondlanguage, thirdlanguage, mathematics, science, social, totalmarks, grade', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'class' => 'Class',
            'studentid' => 'Studentid',
            'examtype' => 'Examtype',
            'firsttlanguage' => 'Firsttlanguage',
            'secondlanguage' => 'Secondlanguage',
            'thirdlanguage' => 'Thirdlanguage',
            'mathematics' => 'Mathematics',
            'science' => 'Science',
            'social' => 'Social',
            'totalmarks' => 'Totalmarks',
            'grade' => 'Grade',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('class',$this->class,true);
        $criteria->compare('studentid',$this->studentid,true);
        $criteria->compare('examtype',$this->examtype,true);
        $criteria->compare('firsttlanguage',$this->firsttlanguage);
        $criteria->compare('secondlanguage',$this->secondlanguage);
        $criteria->compare('thirdlanguage',$this->thirdlanguage);
        $criteria->compare('mathematics',$this->mathematics);
        $criteria->compare('science',$this->science);
        $criteria->compare('social',$this->social);
        $criteria->compare('totalmarks',$this->totalmarks);
        $criteria->compare('grade',$this->grade,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: why these people down voting me, i written my real problem, i am new to yii, if u r expert be like an expert dont do silly things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here [Creating Form](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.view). Since Yii 1.1.1 there is a widget called [CActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm)
 so when you use this widget you create the form inputs with `$form->textField($model,'username')`instead of using `CHtml::activeTextField($model,'username')`but both work in the same way.

So if that field is not being saved in the database it's probably because you haven't added it to the rules of your model.

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('username', 'safe'),
    );
)
```

Comment: What do you want me to check?

Comment: i used chtml for dropdown list - that value is not submitting to database

Comment: Have you added the rules to the model? Are you saving the model in the controller?

Comment: sorry dude, i am adding full code of controller and View  - 1 min

Comment: Which one is the field not being saved?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12481/discussion-between-devendar-and-puigcerber)