# yii-dropdown values are not setting into db

Tags: yii

my 2 dependent dropdowns  exam_type and status are working fine,they displaying values ..but those values are not setting into database..plz help me...this is my code

form view:

---

```
   <tr>
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'exam type :'); ?></td>

<td> 

   <?php echo   CHtml::dropDownList('exam_type','',CHtml::listData(class1::model()->findAll(),'class','class'),array('empty'=>'Choose one',

'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('dynamicstates'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#status', //selector to update


)));

//empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
?>


</td>

<td>    <?php echo $form->error($model,'exam_type'); ?></td>

</tr>
 <tr>
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'status :'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('status','', array());?></td>
<td>    <?php echo $form->error($model,'status'); ?></td>

</tr>
```

### controller view:

```
public function actiondynamicstates()
{

echo $aasd=$_POST['exam_type'];
 echo $data=admission::model()->findAll('class=:class',
              array(':class'=>$aasd));


$data=CHtml::listData($data,'studentid','studentfname');

    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
            echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value), CHtml::encode($name), true);

}
```

Comment: Is your `$_POST` populated when you submit? Does the form validate?

Comment: when we click on submit button,exam_type and status values are not sending to db..its displays cannot be blank.

Comment: Is your `$_POST` populated when you submit?

Comment: no..is there any problem with chtml??

Comment: no it's not populating..

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between form and chtml in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997781/what-is-the-difference-between-form-and-chtml-in-yii)

Answer (score 1):

It most likely that problem in dropdowns names. You should replace

```
CHtml::dropDownList('exam_type'
```

with

```
CHtml::dropDownList(CHtml::activeName($model, 'exam_type'
```

And

```
CHtml::dropDownList('status'
```

with

```
CHtml::dropDownList(CHtml::activeName($model, 'status'
```

Comment: it's not working..                                                  <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList(CHtml::activeName($model,'exam_type','',CHtml::listData(class1::model()->findAll(),'class','class')),array('empty'=>'Choose one',

'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('dynamicstates'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#status', //selector to update
//'data'=>'js:javascript statement'
//leave out the data key to pass all form values through
)));

Answer (score 1):

some days before i too got stuck in this problem.i did some trick to work.

```
   <tr>
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'exam type :'); ?></td>

<td> 

<?php echo   CHtml::dropDownList('exam_type','',CHtml::listData(class1::model()->findAll(),'class','class'),array('empty'=>'Choose one',

'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
 'url'=>CController::createUrl('dynamicstates'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
// 'update'=>'#status', //selector to update
 'update'=>'#modelname_status', //here is the trick replace modelname to orginal model class name 


  )));

 //empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
 ?>
 </td>

 <td>    <?php echo $form->error($model,'exam_type'); ?></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'status :'); ?></td>
  <?php //echo CHtml::dropDownList('status','', array());?>
 <td><?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('modelname[status]','', array());?></td>//same here
   <td>    <?php echo $form->error($model,'status'); ?></td>

    </tr>
```

in above code i changed:

```
 'update'=>'#modelname_status', //here is the trick replace modelname to orginal model class name 

 <td><?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('modelname[status]','', array());?></td>//same here
```

even after it doesnt work give comment.(i didnt test,maybe your controller seems have problem.)

Comment: thank you, i was looking for a solution for my problem and found it on your answer. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem got solved already. If someone is still wondering why those drop-downs do not update the database, they don't because they are not listed as safe attributes. 
Here is an example to make the drop-down-lists  work (only important parts are given) :

Suppose you want to add the field called "showOnHome". First, create a field called "showOnHome" in your database table ( I prefer int(1) as the field type).

**Then, in your model Model :**

```
 public function rules() {
....
....
array('showOnHome','safe'),
}

....
....
 public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
    .....
    .....
    .....
   'showOnHome' => 'Show On Homepage' ,

   )
}
```

**In your View :**

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'showOnHome'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'showOnHome', array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes') , array('empty'=>'--Select--')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'showOnHome'); ?>
</div>
```

**The code snippsets above should do your job if you did not alter the  default controller code generated by Yii, e.g.**

```
/**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Livefuture;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Livefuture']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Livefuture'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Livefuture']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Livefuture'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```